# Дефолтные стили popup расширения браузера

Tags: html, css, браузер

Можно ли изменить дефолтные стили в popup расширения, убрать тень, закруглить края и т.д?

Comment: `popup браузера` если речь про js prompt, alert и т.п. то скорее всего нет. раньше точно нельзя было, да и новости о том чтоб их как то меняли, за последние лет 10 мне что-то не попадались... из того что хоть как то связанно с попапами, вроде только css backdrop появился. но он вообще для сборки своих кастомных попапов из html тегов.

Comment: Нет, я про расширения, когда нажимаешь на иконку расширения справа вверху, вылазит некое окно, которое можно наполнить контентом как обычный html файл, я хотел бы узнать как изменить этого popup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нельзя, это UI браузера и можно менять только лишь то, что внутри окна. Всё, что выходит за его пределы будет обрезано.

Можете относиться к этому окну как к **iframe**, его поведение не сильно отличается.